# What is type of returned array from exec method in RegExp in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My question has a conceptual aspect and one thing is not clear to me.

When I create a regex like `let reg = /javascript/i;` and check it by `exec()` method, it return to me a **Array** of data that seems unusual and it has key/value results.

```js
reg.exec('hello javascript');
// ["javascript", index: 6, input: "hello javascript", groups: undefined]
```

Everything is about the correct result and my question is about the return array mode. I know in JavaScript normally we can't define an array like this but what is the justification for `index`, `input`, and `groups` keys?

When I check this result with `isArray` method, it says this is an array:

```js
Array.isArray(reg.exec('hello javascript'));
// true
```

And when I try to define a array like this, JS return a error to me:

```js
let myArray = ["javascript", index: 6, input: "hello javascript", groups: undefined];
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

Thanks in advance for explaining to me what is happening and I emphasize again that my question is not about the performance of exec or regexp, but about this arrays.

Comment: It's an array but with some extra properties, like `index`; see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#return_value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can I define an array like this?

Comment: Yes, just create an array (`const arr = [1, 2, 3]`) then add properties to it (`arr.foo = "bar"`). There's no literal form, hence the syntax error if you tried to do `[1, 2, 3, foo: "bar"]`, that's just to show you what additional properties there are.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, Thanks... I got what happened.

Comment: I'd like to point out that adding random properties to an array is bad practice. I consider it a mistake `.exec()` does it. Not in the sense of it happened by accident but it was a bad design. IMO, it should have returned an object. Only `.exec()` returns this kind of array to my knowledge, no other native functionality does.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @VLAZ